# Set user_id to null then add it later in rails form/model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an Order app where the customer creates an Order, that Order is then placed in the Order queue where a User(worker) can accept the job and begin working on it. Currently

I am trying to have no `user_id` being associated with an Order until a User accepts the job where their `user_id` is now associated with the Order so that no other User can accept that Order.

Currently an Order `belongs_to :user`and User `has_many :orders`
In my Order migration file I have `t.integer :user_id, null: true`

I am wondering how to make it work so that it takes the null `user_id` until a User accepts the job within a rails form (currently it won't take anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as mentioned by @Mark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44496316/6548745), you need to allow optional association else it will throw error. In your `order.rb`

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

You can initialize new order with order params from your controller, then assign the `user_id` to it when accepted by a user.

```
Order.where(order_params).first_or_create
```

From your form where `user` accepts the order,

```
order = Order.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
unless order.user_id
  order.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
else
  redirect_to some_path, flash: 'Order already taken'
end
```

Comment: where do I put the Order.where(order_params).first_or_create ? sorry just came back to rails!

Comment: in your `create` action of the `orders_controller.rb`

Comment: what is the difference between you and Mark's answer below? Mark's makes it optional whereas yours adds it later on?

Comment: Other answer just pointed out the association error, you anyway have to write the code mentioned in my answer. That's not the complete answer, writing `optional: true` won't assign the `user_id` later automatically.

Comment: it's giving me a "user must exist" error for this, i haven't coded the Order accept part of my app yet though.

Comment: as i mentioned, you have to add `optional: true` to your `belongs_to` association and this code, then it will work fine

Comment: Ahh i see, you edited it which is why I didn't do that. This works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to:

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

Without the second part, it will not allow you to create a record unless it is associated with a User before saving.

EDIT: 4.1.2 gives you all your options:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

Comment: The console returns  INSERT INTO "orders" ("name", "company", "email", "event_type", "country", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") when I have put in my .permit `order_params` that there is a `user_id` is it not showing because it is null or is something gone wrong?