# Issues setting user_id, form/controller won't force change from null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[I asked this question regarding how to set the user_id as null at first then for it to be accepted at a later date.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496222/set-user-id-to-null-then-add-it-later-in-rails-form-model/44496354?noredirect=1#comment75986616_44496354) In that answer is some code that sets my user_id after the order has been created.

Currently am having the issue where I can force a `user_id` in the rails console but when I try to update the `user_id` to something a user's id in an html.erb form it won't work and am unsure why.

In my routes.rb i have set up `post 'accept',to: 'order#accept`

In my order_controller I have set up

```
def accept
  order = Order.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
          unless order.user_id
  order.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
  redirect_to root_path, flash: 'Order accepted'
else
  redirect_to root_path, flash: 'Order already taken'
end
```

end

This is my accept button which should make the `current_user.id` be associated with that order. 
`<button class="btn btn-success"><%=link_to accept_path%> </button>`

I have been trying for ~1hr and cannot find a way to work around, any ideas?

**EDIT** Routes for commenter:

```
        devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }

        root 'welcome#welcome'

        get 'order', to: 'order#new'
        post 'order', to: 'order#create'
        post 'accept', to: 'order#accept'

        get 'dashboard', to: 'order#index'
```

Comment: `order.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)` is failing, is it?

Comment: @Pavan I think so because I do not get redirected at all even though both are meant to go to the `root_path` no matter what ?

Comment: What do you get in the log? can you post it to the question?

Comment: @Pavan just edited, it isn't even going anywhere for some reason

Comment: Not that! Post the log when you click the button.

Comment: @Pavan that is all that shows up in the console

Comment: Try changing `<button class="btn btn-success"><%=link_to accept_path%> </button>` to `<%=link_to accept_path, method: :post, class: "btn btn-success" %>`

Comment: @Pavan that doesn't set the Order to the user_id unfortunately. Start of the console: `Started GET "/dashboard?class=btn+btn-success&method=post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-25 22:59:43 +1200
Processing by OrderController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"class"=>"btn btn-success", "method"=>"post"}`

Comment: This line `order = Order.find_by_id(params[:user_id]) unless order.user_id` doesn't make sense to me? Is there are `order` method in that controller that is able to provide a response for `unless order.used_id` before the first part of the line was processed? Furthermore, does it make sense to query an `Order` by its id but pass a `user_id`? Can you please elaborate on what you want this line to do?

Comment: @spickermann hey, the code was suggested to me in that answer which is why I am using it. I would like that method to update the `order` `user_id` with the `current_user.id`.

Comment: @spickermann added to question now

Answer (score 1):

1) Change the line in the `routes.rb` to

```
post 'accept/:id', to: 'order#accept', as: 'accept'
```

Tip: You might want to consider using resources routing instead of defining all routes yourself.

2) Change the code generating the link to:

```
<button class="btn btn-success">
  <%= link_to accept_path(id: order.id, method: :post) %>
</button>
```

It is unclear from your question if there is an `order` or `@order` defined in your view. But you need to send the `id` of the order you want to accept.

3) Change your controller method to:

```
def accept
  order = Order.find(params[:id])

  if order.user.present?
    redirect_to root_path, flash: 'Order already taken'
  else
    order.update(user_id: current_user.id)
    redirect_to root_path, flash: 'Order accepted'
  end
end
```

Comment: I use an `obj.each do |o|` to get the `id` but now it is saying that undefined method `accept_path`

Comment: the `user_id` is not being associated with the `order`. My models are set up with the correct has_many and belongs_to

Comment: Too little details to debug that issue. Is there an error? What flash message is shown after the redirect? Is `current_user` set? Did you try `update!` to see if there are validation errors?

Comment: Redirect doesn't occur so flash message does not show up. current_user is set.

Comment: Both branches of the `if/else` block end with a `redirect_to`. If there is no redirect at all then that means the queries doesn't hit the controller method or the methods raises an error. I updated 2) in my answer to address this issue.

Comment: No luck, whenever I press the accept button there is nothing about POST and the accept method. All that I can see is `Started GET "/dashboard" for XXX Processing by OrderController#index as HTML then it loads the user and the orders but there is nothing about the order being updated.

Comment: This is definitely not an issue with the routing or the controller anymore. When you clink on the link and the browser requests a completely different route, then you need to debug your HTML and JS. How does the generated link in HTML page look like? Investigate why clicking on that link sends you to `/dashboard` instead of `accept/<an_id>`.

Comment: fixed the issue, needed to use a `get` instead of a `post` for the routing apparently? Thought it would be a `post`

Comment: Using `get` instead of `post` for requests that change data might be a security issue. I suggest to investigate and fix the link building and keep it a `post` request. It feels to me like you did not set up Rails javascript helpers.

Comment: I'm linking it the exact way I do with every rails tutorial i've done so i'm unsure of whats going wrong. I'll look into some POST link tutorials